# How can I set negative niceness of a docker process?

Tags: docker, privileges, nice

I have a testenvironment for code in a docker image which I use by running bash in the container:

```
me@host$ docker run -ti myimage bash
```

Inside the container, I launch a program normally by saying

```
root@docker# ./myprogram
```

However, I want the process of myprogram to have a negative niceness (there are valid reasons for this). However:

```
root@docker# nice -n -7 ./myprogram
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

Given that docker is run by the docker daemon which runs as root and I am root inside the container, why doesn't this work and **how can force a negative niceness**?

*Note: The docker image is running debian/sid and the host is ubuntu/12.04.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding

```
--privileged=true
```

to your run command.

[edit]  privileged=true is the old method.   Looks like

```
--cap-add=SYS_NICE
```

Should work as well.

Comment: `--privileged=true` works like charm (it would appear my docker version is not bleeding edge). Thank you.

Comment: On my system, I got `docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec capabilities: Unknown capability to add: "CAP_CAP_SYS_NICE".` Using `--cap-add=SYS_NICE` worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the CPU priority of the whole container with `-c` for CPU shares.

- **Docker docs**: http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory
- **CGroups/cpu.shares docs**: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt